# Copy data from another table with new id value

Tags: sql

I have a question: I have 3 tables, `Table A`, `Table B` and `Table C`.

`Table A` is the master table whose id column is FK-keyed with `Table B` and `Table C`.

I want to copy the same data from each table and insert those copied rows into its own tables with new id of the `table A`.

We normally do

```
insert into table A (id, name, age) 
   select name, age from table A
```

Here the new rows get a new id because `id` column is auto incremented.

But when we copy the data of `Table B` to `Table B` itself, how we can specify the new id from `Table A` ??? which is FK keyed here.

```
insert into table B (tab_B_Id, id, mark, subject) 
    select id, mark, subject 
    from tab B.

[id is the pk of `Table A` and FK to `Table B` and `Table C`]
```

1. How to insert the newly created id value from table A to other tables ??
2. Is there any way that we can do it without specifying all the column names in the
   both select clause???

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. In SQL Server you can you [`scope identity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) to get the inserted ID. Alternately you can use the [`OUTPUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause in the `INSERT` statement.
2. If you are taking all the columns, you don't need to specify them, otherwise you do. Note that it's good practice to specify columns explicitly. You don't want old code to behave differently if you add a new column.

Comment: `SCOPE_IDENTITY` only works if you insert a single row - it will return the last value for the identity column in your scope; it does not handle inserts of multiple rows

Answer (score 0):

For question 1, how about this:

```
insert into table B (tab_B_Id, mark, subject) select mark, subject from tab B
```

then

```
insert into table B(id) where tab_B_Id="THE ID VALUE THAT YOU GENERATED EARLIER" select id from table A
```

I didn't test the code though. There might have some syntax errors.
I don't quite understand your question 2.

Comment: hi sakura, thanks for the reply. for the answer 1, how insert the id value (which is the new id value from table A - master table) ??

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. for the answer 1, how i will insert the id value from table A ? The master table Table A has id column which a PK and auto incremented. This id is referenced as FK in Table B. So when we copy 2 rows from Table A and insert those copied 2 rows to the same table, ie, Table A, new id values will be inserted for the copied row. Now come to the Table B. When we do the same thing to Table B, how i will insert the id value of Table A which is referenced as FK to Table B ?? My 2nd Q was, w/o specifying all the col names in select clause, is there any way we can do it ?

Comment: Oh... How about "insert into table B(id, mark, subject) select id from table A"? The mark and subject should be the values that you want to insert. I suppose the tab_B_Id is a PK in table B so it should be auto-incremented, just like the id in table A.